# How does this dot notation within SQL work?

Tags: sql, table-alias

I'm working with some SQL and trying to understand what is going on.

Within the select there are what seem like variables `s.id` `s.status`

```
with 
    last_transactions as (
        select 
            s.id as station_id, 
            s.status as status,
            case...........
```

What are these `s.` items and how do they work?

Comment: They are *qualified column references*.  The `s` is resolved in the `FROM` clause.  The part after the `.` is the column name.

Comment: Table s, column id.

Answer (score 1):

`.` notation is used to reference columns mainly of a table, view etc. schema objects or an aliased name of a schema object as above you have used s as alias name of some table so using `s.` the part after dot references to the column in that s or table aliased

Answer (score 1):

the `s` is the table name. `s.id` means the id column of the `s table`.

Answer (score 1):

`s.` is a reference to the table name that derives from the `From` clause that probably follows in your query. The part after the `.` is the column name.

For example `s.id` means: Column 'id' from table 's'

Answer (score 1):

`S` is table alias and through `.`dot we can access that table column.

Example..

```
Select S.id from Sample as S
```

It give you all id's of the sample table.